# How to draw arrow and loop with rounded heads instead of arrow shapes?

Tags: diagrams, nodes

Can any one help me with this. I want to draw an arrow and a loop with rounded nodes as in the image?

[image]

I am waiting for your expertise.

Answer (score 5):

I used [TikZ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf); for your specific question about the arrow tips, I used the arrows library (see **Section 23 Arrow Tip Library** of the pgf manual). The following code can be used as a starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  myloop/.style={to path={.. controls +(50:1) and +(-50:1) .. (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
  mytext/.style={draw,fill=white,font=\footnotesize,align=center},
  myellipse/.style={draw,ellipse, x radius=1cm, text width=4cm, text height=1.3cm}
]

\node[myellipse] at (0,0) (top) {};
\node[myellipse] at (0,-4) (bottom) {};
\node[draw,circle, inner sep=10pt] at ($(top.center)+(-1,0)$) (dutch) {};
\node[draw,circle, inner sep=10pt] at ($(top.center)+(1,0)$) (english) {};

\foreach \x/\y in {-1.2/-3.5,-0.6/-3.7,-0.9/-3.8,-1.2/-4.1,-0.9/-4.1,-0.6/-4.1,-1/-4.4,-0.7/-4.4}
  \draw (\x,\y) circle [radius=2pt];
\foreach \x/\y in {1.2/-3.5,0.6/-3.7,0.9/-3.8,1.2/-4.1,0.9/-4.1,0.6/-4.1,1/-4.4,0.7/-4.4}
  \fill (\x,\y) circle [fill=black,radius=2pt];

\draw[*-,ultra thick] (bottom.5) to [myloop] (bottom.355);
\draw[-latex,ultra thick,shorten >=3pt] (-1,-3.5) -- (dutch);
\draw[-latex,ultra thick,shorten >=3pt] (1,-3.5) -- (english);
\draw[*-,ultra thick,shorten >=3pt] (-0.8,-3.5) -- (english);
\draw[*-,ultra thick,shorten >=3pt] (0.8,-3.5) -- (dutch);
\draw[->,ultra thick,shorten >=3pt] (-0.8,-5.5) -- (-0.8,-4.5);
\draw[-*,ultra thick,shorten >=3pt] (0.8,-5.5) -- (0.8,-4.5);

\node[mytext] at (-1,0.7) {DUTCH};
\node[mytext] at (1,0.7) {ENGLISH};
\node[mytext] at (-2.2,-4) {DUTCH\\ WORDS};
\node[mytext] at (2,-4) {ENGLISH\\ WORDS};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.I run the script and got the message: ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/x radius' and I am going 
to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
Do I need to install any package?

Comment: @expling You need to update your PGF version. My code requires PGF version 2.10 but you surely have an older version. To find out the version installed in your system run the document `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pgfversion
\end{document}` Update your PGF version and my code will work.

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo. I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and pgf version is 2.00. Is there any way to update the pgf to 2.10 without upgrading my OS to ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: @expling: did you install your LaTeX system from Ubuntu's repositories? If so, I would suggest you remove that installation and to do a TeX Live2011 fresh installation directly from [TUG](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) (Ubuntu's repositories contain quite old LaTeX distributions (even in Ubuntu 11.10)).